# How to use  the not clause with select

Tags: java, mysql

In the following query:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM racetimes WHERE course='" + myracecoursevariable + "'";
```

I want to change the query and select data from database where the course is not equal to the dynamic variable given in the query in MYSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM racetimes WHERE not (course='" + myracecoursevariable + "')";
```

or

```
"SELECT * FROM racetimes WHERE course <> '" + myracecoursevariable + "'";
```

You should be using prepared statements to pass dynamic variables to MySQL

Answer (score 3):

You may use not equal `<>` instead of equal `=`:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM racetimes WHERE course <> '" + myracecoursevariable + "'";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
query = "SELECT * FROM racetimes WHERE course <> '" + myracecoursevariable + "'";
```

The `<>` means `NOT EQUAL`, while `=` means `EQUAL`.

**PS**. I would rather learn how to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of doing `'" + myracecoursevariable + "'";` (See an example from [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)).

Answer (score 2):

1. Never build queries by string concatenation - this is asking for issues down the road (SQL injection, "'" characters in the race course, etc). In Java, use `PreparedStatement` with the `?` placeholders.
2. The `!=`  operation in SQL is `<>`

Comment: I hope the OP takes note of this!

Comment: In MySQL, `<>` and `!=` are equivalent.